# Reference missing path - Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-8

I made an application using Visual Studio 2012 for Windows Store App. I want to use the Sqlite and already download the SDK. After I add into Reference there is a warning and the path was missing.

[image: Missing reference path]

[image]

[image]

I try to download the sample project of the sqlite and when I check the reference, it ok with full path on the properties.

[image]

[image]

[image]

The question is, **how can I set the path of the reference manually?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the problem:

When I'm creating new project, the debug configuration is set to "Any CPU".
[image]

And the SDK is for x86, when I change my configuration from "Any CPU" to "x86", it resolve the missing path automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Existing references cannot be edited. you have to re-add it to the folder, thus removing the incorrect references.

You can add a new reference to the libraries. Just rightmouseclick on the "reference" folder, choose "Add reference". A new window appears. Then use the "Browse" section. Don't also forget to ensure that the libraries will be copied when you're running/debugging it. (to provide not missing libraries when publishing your app).

Comment: Yeah, already did it, but the warning always shows. And when I try to add reference again, the checkbox didn't checked.

Comment: i have also VS 2012 on win8, but could add references to libraries in and out project folder without problems.